# How to appropriately specify a local macro to exclude negative values?

Tags: stata

I have a set of continuous variables `v1, v2, v3, v4` which occasionally have negative values, meaning not applicable. I want to create variable `v5` as an overall representation of those variables, which should exclude negative values, as follows:

```
gen v5 = .
local locvar v1 v2 v3 v4  
replace v5 = (v1 + v2 + (v3/5) + (v4/5))/4.5 if `locvar' >= 0
```

But this doesn't work. It says: `invalid 'v2'` How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best long-term solution by far is to use `mvdecode` to recode negative values as missing values. Note that if negative values are informative about reasons for, or kinds of, missingness, then you can use extended missing values (`.a` to `.z`). Otherwise you will have to implement work-arounds for every calculation involving these variables to avoid the negative values being taken literally.

Otherwise note that expressions such as `max(v1, 0)` return `0` if `v1` is negative and `v1` otherwise.

I'll ignore the detail of dividing some values by `5` and the total by `4.5` for which there is presumably is a logic that is not central to the question.

Here is how to get a total of the positive values only.

`gen total = max(v1, 0) + max(v2, 0) + max(v3, 0) + max(v4, 0)`

Here is how to get a count of the positive values.

`gen count = (v1 > 0) + (v2 > 0) + (v3 > 0) + (v4 > 0)`

as true or false evaluations in Stata yield 1 when an expression is true and 0 otherwise.

If you had 42 such variables, say, not 4, you should prefer to write a loop:

```
gen total = 0 
gen count = 0 

quietly forval j = 1/42 { 
    replace total = total + max(v`j', 0) 
    replace count = count + (v`j' > 0) 
}
```

and so forth.

If any of the variables were missing, `max(`*missing*`, 0)` is returned as `0`, but you would need some condition such as

```
v`j' > 0 & v`j' < .
```

or

```
inrange(v`j', 0, .)
```

to catch being positive (and not being missing).

Note: Your guessed solution is not fixable. You have to work on each variable to specify that you want positive values only. Local macros are useful for any loop, as above.

Comment: Thank you. I tried that from experience with SAS array but, as you suggested, it didn't work anyway.

Comment: Glad to help. I see you've asked 11 questions, and accepted just 3 answers. Your choice, but you would gain reputation by accepting answers.

Comment: Thanks for your reminder. For the most part the reason is because I haven't verified the suggested solutions. But I'll give them some review.

Comment: Seems strange to ask a question, then not check what works!

Comment: Sometimes I figure it out but it's different. Often times mine is more rudimentary than the solutions. But I've given them a look.